Hilt error ActivityContext cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method
I have setup Hilt as
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)
object CredentialModule {

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideActivityContext(
        @ActivityContext context: Context
    ) = context

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideFirebaseAuth(): FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideCredentialManager(
        context: Context
    ): CredentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context)

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideGetGoogleIdOption(
        context: Context
    ): GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
        .setServerClientId(context.getString(R.string.web_client_id))
        .setAutoSelectEnabled(false)
        .build()

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideGetCredentialRequest(
        getGoogleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption
    ) = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
        .addCredentialOption(getGoogleIdOption)
        .build()

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideAuthDataSource(
        context: Context,
        auth: FirebaseAuth,
        credentialManager: CredentialManager,
        getCredentialRequest: GetCredentialRequest
    ) = AuthDataSource(context, auth, credentialManager, getCredentialRequest)

} 

This always throws error saying
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ActivityContext android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements ProfileApp_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
  
      @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ActivityContext android.content.Context is injected at
          [com.being.coder.app.profile.ProfileApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC] com.being.coder.app.profile.di.CredentialModule.provideActivityContext(context)
      android.content.Context is injected at
          [com.being.coder.app.profile.ProfileApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC] com.being.coder.app.profile.di.CredentialModule.provideAuthDataSource(context, �)
      com.being.coder.app.profile.data.datasource.AuthDataSource is injected at
          [com.being.coder.app.profile.ProfileApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC] com.being.coder.app.profile.di.CredentialModule.provideAuthRepository(authDataSource)
      com.being.coder.app.profile.presentation.signin.repository.AuthRepository is injected at
          [com.being.coder.app.profile.ProfileApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC] com.being.coder.app.profile.di.CredentialModule.provideAuthUseCases(authRepository)
      com.being.coder.app.profile.domain.usecase.auth.AuthUseCases is injected at
          [com.being.coder.app.profile.ProfileApp_HiltComponents.ViewModelC] com.being.coder.app.profile.ui.screens.auth.AuthViewModel(authUseCases)
      com.being.coder.app.profile.ui.screens.auth.AuthViewModel is injected at
          [com.being.coder.app.profile.ProfileApp_HiltComponents.ViewModelC] com.being.coder.app.profile.ui.screens.auth.AuthViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          [com.being.coder.app.profile.ProfileApp_HiltComponents.ViewModelC] dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.being.coder.app.profile.ProfileApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.being.coder.app.profile.ProfileApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.being.coder.app.profile.ProfileApp_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
  
  Note: @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ActivityContext android.content.Context is provided in the following other components:
      [com.being.coder.app.profile.ProfileApp_HiltComponents.ActivityC] dagger.hilt.android.internal.modules.ActivityModule.provideContext(�)

I have tried to fix this issue using @ApplicationContext, but CredentialManager.create(context) needs Activity Context, How can I get Activity Context in above case, so that I can get rid of:
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ActivityContext android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.


Okay so I think this can be done as two ways first to directly use the @ActivityContext directly wherever its needed. But I guess you don't need that.
So, here's my second approach, do give it a try. You provide the @ActivityContext in ActivityComponent.
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object ContextModule {

      @Provides
      @ActivityScoped
      fun provideActivityContext(
        @ActivityContext context: Context
      ) = context

}

@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)
object CredentialModule {

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideFirebaseAuth(): FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideCredentialManager(
        context: Context
    ): CredentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context)

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideGetGoogleIdOption(
        context: Context
    ): GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
        .setServerClientId(context.getString(R.string.web_client_id))
        .setAutoSelectEnabled(false)
        .build()

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideGetCredentialRequest(
        getGoogleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption
    ) = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
        .addCredentialOption(getGoogleIdOption)
        .build()

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideAuthDataSource(
        context: Context,
        auth: FirebaseAuth,
        credentialManager: CredentialManager,
        getCredentialRequest: GetCredentialRequest
    ) = AuthDataSource(context, auth, credentialManager, getCredentialRequest)
}


Man! Already mentioned that @ApplicationContext context: Context, does not work in my case.

My Bad, i didn't notice that. I have updated the answer, do give it a try.

According to the documentation, you should use activity-based context for methods like getCredential, but you can use application context for create. In fact, if you use activity context for an ActivityRetainedScoped CredentialManager, it will cause a memory leak by retaining the initial activity context, because CredentialManager will survive configuration changes, while Activity won't.
//    @Provides
//    @ActivityRetainedScoped
//    fun provideActivityContext(
//        @ActivityContext context: Context
//    ) = context

    @Provides
    @ActivityRetainedScoped
    fun provideCredentialManager(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): CredentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context)

